# Search pattern for a backup file names

Tags: c#

What would be a search pattern that I could use with `Directory.GetFiles(rootFolderPath, fileSearchPattern);` that would return all files that have `someName.xxx.txt` where `xxx` is a sequential number like 001, 002, 003 etc. Basically if the file doesn't end with `*.txt` but has `*.*.txt` type of name I want to grab it.

`filename.001.txt`
`filename.002.txt`
`filename.010.txt` .....etc.

Comment: Did you try "*.*.txt"? Seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @konrad Do you think a pattern in `GetFiles` is **faster** than get all files list then filter?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp sorry but "..txt" yields no results. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @LeiYang I might have to do that. It looks like that's what others are also suggesting down below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for files that contain `.` in the name that is not part of the extension, then I recommend not using the `GetFiles` method with a pattern search due to the way the pattern is passed through to the Windows API which gets confused with periods in file names. Instead, you can filter with Linq and Regex, something like this:

```
var regexPattern = @".*\.\d{3}\.txt";

var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\wired\Documents")
    .Where(f => Regex.IsMatch(f, regexPattern));
```